# Storing data in the tree map input during a whole minute before serializing it

Tags: java, time, treemap

```
    public class StoreMessage extends Thread implements Serializable{

        private static long startNanotime=System.nanoTime();
        private static int timeToRun = 60000; // 1 minute
        private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        private static long runUntilMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeToRun;
        public static Map <Long,Message> map1=Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<Long,Message>());
        public static void store(Message message)throws Exception{
        while (true) {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (now >= runUntilMillis) {
                   break;
              }
                long preciseTime=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(now)+(System.nanoTime()-startNanotime);
                map1.put(preciseTime, message);
            }
         }

        public static byte[] returning()throws Exception
        { 
            map1.clear();
            return Serializer.serialize(map1);
         }

   }
```

This code store multiple command line arguments to a tree map with in and serializes it. How do I modify it in such a manner that it stores all the arguments recieved with in a minute..be it multiple arguments at a time or one by one with a gap of few seconds?Once a minute is over,the tree map is to be cleared and serialized. And once cleared, start receiving data from the next minute.
Eg. Suppose my user starts to input his data at 9.19 pm where he inputs multiple messages at the same time. He inputs some more at say 9.19.38 secs. Then suppose he inputs some more data at 9.20 pm and then stops. What my code does is, it lets he input multiple messages at 9.19pm, stores it to a tree map, then after a minute,serializes it and does not allow him to input data at 9.19.38 secs but he is able to input data at 19.20 on the cleared map.
What I was looking at doing was, store all of his data received at 9.19pm, wait till 19.20..since user input more messages at 19.19.38pm, write them to the same map and then at 19.20 serialize it and clear it, so that I can start to store messages at 19.20.
What changes do I make...? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

A few ways of doing that.
First thought would be to have some sort of queue. 
Throw content at it.
When the earliest message goes over a minute, extract a minutes worth throw it at a thread to serialise whatever it's passed. It shouldn't really care how much there is.

You are trying to do too many things at once in a single "function" as far as I can see.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain the same result using tree maps? For I need the keys for reference in another program code linked to it.

Comment: Well you don't have to destroy the keys, you just need them to be removed/ discounted from the queue that manages the serialisations. Sounds like you are bit too tightly coupled in more places than this to me. Break things up, the best way to manage complexity, is to keep as much as you can simple.

Comment: I really dont follow you..I need the keys to be serialized too..Could you please provide an example for the same?

Comment: No, I dopn't know what 99% of your code is doing. All I was saying is have one thread to manage when things get serialised and another to serialise whatever needs serialising, things wil become a lot simpler...